# New input not posted

Tags: php, html, forms, post, xdebug

I've got a form with 6 inputs of different types (select, radio, text...). When I debug with  Xdebugg I can see the values in $_POST variable,

I've decided to add other input but they arent posted : when I look at $_POST variable, I just have the first 6 values.

Here's a part of my form :
edit : i've copy/paste the code this time. **My boss told me to not send the real code, that's why I've send a fake code** but i really need some help so here's the real one.

```
<div id="modifierUser" class="divAdmin">                                
   <form id="modifierUserForm" name="modifier_user"action="includes/inc_adminModifierUser.php">
      <fieldset>
         <legend>
            <img src="img/bulle_48.png" alt="bulle" title="bulle" />
            <h3>Modifier le compte</h3><br />
         </legend>
         <!-- the field i've tried to add -->
         <label class ="labelEmail" for="idmembre">ID du membre </label>
         <input id="idmembre" name="idmembre" size="35" class="required"/>
         <!-- -->

         <label class ="labelEmail" for="pseudo">Utilisateur </label>
         <input id="pseudo" name="pseudo" size="35" class="required"/>

         <label class ="labelEmail" for="anneeNaiss">Ann&eacute;e de naissance </label>
         <input id="anneeNaiss" name="anneeNaiss" placeholder="e.g : 1984" size="35" class="required" maxlength="4" value="" />

         <label class ="labelEmail" for="email">Email </label>
         <input id="mail" type="email" name="email" size="35" class="email" value="" maxlength="50"/>

         <label class ="labelEmail" for="telephone">T&eacute;l&eacute;phone</label>
         <input id="telephone" type="tel" name="telephone" size="35" class="required" value="" maxlength="10" />

         <label class ="labelEmail"> Masquer num&eacute;ro dans l'annonce</label>
         <input type="radio" name="masquerTel" value="oui" id="oui" checked="checked" />
         <span>Oui</span>
         <input type="radio" name="masquerTel" value="non" id="non" /><span>Non</span>

         <label class ="labelEmail" for="region">R&eacute;gion</label>
         <select id="region" name="region" size="1" class="required" style="width:180px"
            <option value="Aquitaine" selected="selected" >Aquitaine </option>
            <option value="Alsace">Alsace </option>
            <!-- There's many options there-->
        </select>

        <input type="submit" name="enregistrer" value="Enregistrer les modifications" size="35"/>
        <input type="button" name="annuler" class="annuler" value="ANNULER" />    
     </fieldset>   
  </form>                            
</div><!--fin modifierUser-->
```

variable i can see :

$_POST['pseudo']

$_POST['anneNaiss']

$_POST['email']

$_POST['telephone']

$_POST['masquerTel']

$_POST['region']

i'll always have $_POST[6]in xdebug, no matter how many input i add. But i tried to suppress one of 6 above input and i got $_POST[5].

The one I need to see 
$_POST['idmembre']

Sorry for wasting your time

Comment: Which is the field you are trying to add? Can you post how are you trying it?

Comment: Careful! You have `ation` instead of `action` on the first  line.

Comment: it's write 'ation' instead of 'action' because I didnt copy/paste the code : i've typed it. But in my code, i've correctly type 'action'.

Comment: Steve -> Those are the originals fields.

Comment: I would use something like TamperData on FF or Firebug to look if the browser sends the data or not

Comment: @user2067794 that's why I ask you to post the field you are trying to add. Maybe the problem it's in that field.

Comment: here's the new field i've tried to add                                   <label class ="labelEmail" for="realname">real name </label>
<input id="inp_realname" name="realname" size="35" "/>

Comment: I am using xdebug. Do TamperDAta or Firebug show more informations?

Comment: i've tried to watch with Firebug, same result

Comment: can you post all form fields in question? So we can debug your code.

Comment: It's isn't a POST form so it's impossible that you see the previous values in `$_POST`. It's obvious that you're still not posting the real code.

Comment: alvaro -> seems like i dont have method in my own form in the real code.. but i can see the previous values...so weird

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if the values aren't being posted because you've mispelt "action", calling it "ation" in the form element starting tag. `<form>`.

Because of this your form will be posting to the same page it's output in, rather than the page you're trying to POST the data to.

**The first line of your code should look like this instead:**

```
<form id="modifyUserForm" name="modify_user" action="includes/inc_adminModifyUser.php">
```

Comment: action attribute has a default, so that might give another problem, not what OP was describing

Comment: @kms Yes, it does; it will default to sending the data to page the form is output on; which may be causing the problem.

Comment: I was thinking because I might have misunderstood "when I look at $_POST, I only have the first six"

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you have an extra double quote in your code so thats normal you HTML code does not render correctly:

```
 <input id="inp_realname" name="realname" size="35" "/>
```

should be:

```
 <input id="inp_realname" name="realname" size="35" />
```